# powerpoint transparent prints black

Tags: printing, transparency, microsoft-powerpoint

In Powerpoint, I have a White box with a transparent outline.  This does not appear on the document, and this is deliberate, I only use the reference points for connecting lines.  However, when I print the page, or go to print preview, the box has a thick black outline. I have tried a transparent outline, and a white outline.

I use Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010 on Windows 7 Enterprise x64.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the shape outline to none via the format-ribbon.